# AWS S3 403 access denied issue with nodeJS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, multer, multer-s3

The following is my bucket policy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AddCannedAcl",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "==mydetails=="
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::etcetera-dev/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "s3:x-amz-acl": "public-read"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

This is my Iam user inline policy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Now I'm trying to upload a file using multer-s3 with `acl:'public-read'` and I am getting 403 access denied. If I don't use acl property in multer, I am able to upload with no issues.

Answer (score 0):

You may have fixed this now, but if you haven't, there a many different possible fixes (See: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-troubleshoot-403/).

But I ran into the same problem, and what fixed it for me was the following.
I presume you're calling `s3.upload()` when trying to upload your file. I found that if there is not Bucket parameter within your `upload()` options, you will also receive a 403.

i.e ensure your `upload()` call is as the following:

```
await s3.upload({
  Bucket: // some s3Config.Bucket
  Body: // Stream or File,               
  Key: // Filename,  
  ContentType: // Mimetype 
}).promise();
```

`Bucket: // some s3Config.Bucket` - I was missing this param in the function-call as I thought that `new AWS.S3(config)` handled the bucket. Turns out, you should always add the bucket to your upload params.